# I have to input the same string twice to get 'else if' code to run

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am required to use if else-if else statements within Java (honestly not my first choice) all works properly except all the statements that come second always need to be entered twice.

i.e.: "Enter A or B." A works on first enter. B must be entered twice.

```
public static void exampleMethod(){
 if(input.next().equals("A")){
        System.out.println("This is said when A is input.");
    }
    else if(input.next().equals("B")){
        System.out.println("This is said when B is input");
        }
    else    
        exampleMethod(); //returns to top of method; 
}
```

Otherwise the code works fine, and everything under "B" does run after entering twice, but I need it to work so that it registers B when it's entered the first time and not having to enter "B" then "B" again to have it run. This also happens with switches 
like:

```
switch(input.next()){
   case "A":
    System.out.println("A pressed");
    break;
   case "B":
    System.out.println("B pressed");
    break;
  default:
    exampleMethod();
 }
```

Is this one of those annoying Java moments? Because I've done something similar with C# and it works fine.

Comment: `public static void` works? JavaScript or Java?

Comment: You should read the value of `input.next()` into a variable and then compare that in your `if` statements. Otherwise I believe that you are calling it twice if you reach your "B" statement.

Comment: Please don't mix if-else constructs with and without curly braces. I - like I think many others - will find that very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

As said @MattJones said, `input.next()` read the input, so you shouldn't use it directly in your if else block.

Instead read the value and then do the if/then

```
public static void exampleMethod() {
    String inputValue = input.next();
    if (inputValue.equals("A")) {
        System.out.println("This is said when A is input.");
    } else if (inputValue.equals("B")) {
        System.out.println("This is said when B is input");
    } else {
        exampleMethod(); // returns to top of method;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using next() it's eating the Enter key press use another next() to eat the buffer or use nextLine() to take the whole line.

Comment: This is fundamentally correct, but PLEASE explain that in a more detailed fashion so that somebody who doesn't already know that will also understand it. Use some interpunctuation so that the sentences become more readable.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt Jones says in his comment, this will work fine in Java (i assume is java code as Dan says)

```
String str = input.next();
switch(str){
   case "A":
    System.out.println("A pressed");
    break;
   case "B":
    System.out.println("B pressed");
    break;
  default:
    exampleMethod();
 }
```

and with if else

```
String str = input.next();
if(str.equals("A")){
        System.out.println("This is said when A is input.");
    }
    else if(str.equals("B")){
        System.out.println("This is said when B is input");
        }
    else    
        exampleMethod(); //returns to top of method;
```

Otherwhise input.next() is called once per comparation, and as it is a blocking operation (needs interaction with user) ends up with you having to press 'B' twice.

Hope this helps